I.S.S. greatest number on board
What is the greatest number of humans who have ever simultaneously been on board the International Space Station, and when did that occur?

Welcome to Stack Exchange! Don't worry too much about your first question being closed as duplicate. Take some time to look around, see what questions have already been asked, notice that questions need to contain some evidence of prior research so they don't look like "please look this up for me" and when you are ready, please feel free to ask another question. thanks!
